# Creating a freemarker macro with optional nested content?

Tags: freemarker

What is the proper way to create a macro that can be used with or without nested content? e.g.

```
<@myMacro/>
<@myMacro>my nested content</@myMacro>
```

Is there something like this? Or something else?

```
<#macro myMacro>
  <#if ??????>
    Before nested content
    <#nested/>
    After nested content
  <#else/>
    Nothing nested here
  </#if>
</#macro>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nested content is assigned to a variable and then this variable is checked if it has any content. The variable is then sent to the output instead of using another nested directive to avoid the content being processed twice.

```
<#macro myMacro>
    <#assign nested><#nested/></#assign>

    <#if nested?has_content>
        Before nested content
        ${nested}
        After nested content
    <#else/>
       Nothing nested here
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

Comment: My uneducated gut reaction is to suspect that this approach, if used often and to surround large blocks, could cause freemarker to do a lot of additional temporary memory allocation and to then also require a lot of extra garbage collection. Can anyone comment if my concern is a real concern or not?  If it is a real concern, then are there ways to avoid this problem?

Comment: I think you're right. I guess it depends just how often and how large the content is. The only other way I can think of is to pass a boolean parameter which is used to decide if content the content surrounding the nested directive is shown.

Comment: Make sure you use `<#local .../>` instead of `<#assign .../>` while working with variables inside a macro or you will likely to have troubles with nested calls of macros (like `<@myMacro> <@myMacro/> </@myMacro>`)